# Outbound SOAP Handler to edit full SOAPMessage

Tags: java, xml, soap, handler, jmx-ws

Is there a way to retrieve the full `SOAP` message to handle it (envelope and all) when using the `javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage` class?

I am using `JMX-WS` and want to edit the outbound `SOAP` Message from the server, in order to append two characters to the message AFTER the end closing tag of the envelope, as the client legacy code is expecting it. So ideally I would like to be able to edit the full message as a `String`, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with cxf :

http://www.mastertheboss.com/web-interfaces/337-apache-cxf-interceptors.html

Take a look at the `LogInterceptor` example